# Get month numbe passing only month name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the month no when I only knows month name. 
(If month name January should return 1)

I tried this.

```
SELECT DATEPART(MM,'january 01 2011')
```

But here I want to pass whole date value(january 01 2011). But I only need to pass month name.
(Without using 'Case')

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [Stay away from lazy shorthand](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx). Does it take that much longer to type `MONTH` and make your code self-documenting to boot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass month name and append `01 2011` (or whatever other day + year you wish) to it, like this:

```
@declare monthName varchar(20);
@set monthName = 'january';

SELECT DATEPART(MM,monthName+' 01 2011')
```

or

```
SELECT MONTH(monthName+' 01 2011')
```

Comment: here I need to pass year also. any way to do this by passing only the month name?

Comment: @Tom - You **are** passing only a single variable - `monthName`.

Comment: Note this isn't safe if you pass the string `January` but the user executing the code actually has a different language setting (e.g. try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;`). A months table could protect you from this if it's a concern.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `Case`

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(15)='mar'

SELECT CASE @month
         WHEN 'Jan' THEN 1
         WHEN 'feb' THEN 2
         WHEN 'mar' THEN 3
         WHEN 'apr' THEN 4
         WHEN 'may' THEN 5
         WHEN 'jun' THEN 6
         WHEN 'jul' THEN 7
         WHEN 'aug' THEN 8
         WHEN 'sep' THEN 9
         WHEN 'oct' THEN 10
         WHEN 'nov' THEN 11
         WHEN 'dec' THEN 12
       END
```

Comment: this is ok. But i'm searching the solution in less lines. (Without using case)

Answer (score 0):

```
@declare monthName varchar(20);
@set monthName = 'JUNE';

SELECT DATEPART(MM,monthName+' 01 2014') //Monthname +'any date and year'
```